# python xml.etree.ElementTree add subelement to parent based on subelement text

Tags: python, elementtree

I have the following example xml file:

```
<root>
 <input_file>
   <type>x</type>
 </input_file>
 <input_file>
   <type>y</type>
 </input_file>
</root>
```

And would like to add a subelement based on the `<type>` tag using python xml.etree.ElementTree.  Example:

Add `<path></path>` tag with text 'z' to `<type>x</type>` such as:

```
<root>
 <input_file>
   <type>x</type>
   <path>z</path>
 </input_file>
 <input_file>
   <type>y</type>
 </input_file>
</root>
```

Here is my try at the python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file = 'test.xml'

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for input_file in root.findall('input_file'):

    type_element = input_file.find('type')

    if type_element.text == 'x':

        c = ET.SubElement(input_file, 'path')

        c.text('z')
        
print (ET.tostring(root))
```

I receive a typeError:

```
c.text('z')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I understand it would be easier if type would be an attribute instead a child tag (i.e `<input_file type='x'></input_file>`

But that is not the case.

Is there a parent-child relationship that I need to initiate first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, `c.text` is not a method, it is an instance variable. You can check this against the output of `help(c)`. Change the method call to an assignment statement.

```
     |  Data descriptors defined here:
     |  
     |  attrib
     |      A dictionary containing the element's attributes
     |  
     |  tag
     |      A string identifying what kind of data this element repre
sents
     |  
     |  tail
     |      A string of text directly after the end tag, or None
     |  
     |  text
     |      A string of text directly after the start tag, or None
```

```py
c.text = "z"
```

Or you can assign `c.text` in the call to `c.__init__`

```py
c = ET.SubElement(input_file, 'path', text="z")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element

Comment: Thank you.  I will make an effort to look at the docs more closely next time :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't sweat it. I've used `xml.etree.ElementTree` for years and just did the assignment. Today I learned that I can assign attributes within the initializer call.